# Increase supported devices android store

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Count of supported devices of my android app is only 380 instead of 4500+ ;

Here is part of my manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
    <permission
        android:name="*.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="*.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Project build target is Google APIs 4.3 and added as library  google-play-service_lib.

So what's wrong and what to do to make Google play let app to be visible for more devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
```

That limits the app to devices with that version of open GL.  3.0 is only supported on devices with Android 4.3 or higher, which is a small percentage of all devices.  If you need OpenGL 3.0, you're limited to just those 400ish devices.

Also note that not all 4.3 devices will support it, it also requires software driver and hardware support

Comment: Thanks , 4038 supporting devices now )